# Будет ли переполнение double при

Tags: java, c#, c

Есть переменная типа double. Каждый раз её увеличивают на 0.01. Будет ли переполнение?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

С точки зрения теории формата IEEE-754 переполнение при последовательном увеличении числа типа `double` может наступить только в одном случае: когда операция сложения выполняется с округлением в сторону плюс бесконечности (если исходное число НЕ было бесконечностью). В процессоре по-умолчанию установлен другой флаг округления (nearest-to-even), по какой причине вы никогда не доберётесь до бесконечности, так как, начиная с какого-то момента, прибавление `0,01` перестанет увеличивать вашу переменную.

Происходит это потому, что формат с плавающей запятой хранит только самые старшие биты числа. Представьте себе, что (работаем в десятичной системе), у вас в памяти могут храниться только 3 цифры числа. То есть вместо  `12345` вы можете хранить только `123 * 10^2`. Тогда попробуйте прибавить число `1` Если бы вы могли хранить все 5 цифр, получили бы `12346`, но ведь это то же самое, что и было: `123 * 10^2`. Ваше прибавление `1` ничего не поменяло, потому что вы уже потеряли последние две цифры из-за ограничений памяти самого формата.

Подробнее об этом можно почитать в [статье](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/unexpected-effects/), где разбирается пример "игрушечного" формата на подобии IEEE-754 и показано как при прибавлении к большому числу маленького первое не меняется.

Ответ на ваш вопрос: НЕТ.

Естественно, мой ответ справедлив для машинной реализации плавающей арифметики в формате IEEE-754, есть много других форматов, там ситуация может быть иной.

Answer (score -2):

Нет.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double v=1000000000000.0*10000000000000.0;
    cout<<((v!=v+0.01) ? "Yes" : "No");

    return 0;
}
```

В какой-то момент просто прибавления не будет.

Comment: Не годится в ответы. Нет ни о природе float32/float64, ни о нормализации операндов. Ответ из разряда "просто потому что" не подходит для базы знаний.