# Почему Float.MAX_VALUE-1 == Float.MAX_VALUE – true?

Tags: java, float, double

1. Почему Float.MAX_VALUE-1 == Float.MAX_VALUE – true?
2. Какие максимальные числа для float и double, с которыми такой проблемы не будет?

Comment: Я писал об этом же здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041591/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-double-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8/1041619#1041619

Comment: Максимальное число, от которого вы можете безнаказанно вычесть 1 для типа данных float (32 бит) по идее должно быть равно `33554430`, но это не точно, надо считать. Главное, что не факт, что числа меньше будут обладать тем же свойством, потому что `33554428` при попытке отнят один всё равно останется тем же. Но, опять же, считать надо, я навскидку сказал.

Comment: Float.MAX_VALUE - число, которое если записать его не в экспоненциальной форме, будет иметь 39 разрядов. Вы делаете изменения в самом младшем разряде на единицу. Это изменение никак не может быть отображено с точностью предоставляемой типом Float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала рассмотрим аналогию, которая пояснит ситуацию. Представьте, что вы имеете возможность хранить только 3 десятичные цифры и вам нужно записать число `12345`. Не получится, но вы можете сохранить его в другом формате: `123 * 10**2`. Именно так (упрощённо говоря) и работает арифметика с плавающей запятой: хранятся только самые старшие биты числа и порядок (сдвиг, степень, экспонента - как хотите, так и называйте).

Теперь вы хотите отнять единицу. Ну давайте попробуем вместе: `12345 - 1 = 12344`. Однако вы можете хранить только 3 цифры, стало быть, имеем `123 * 10**2`, а это в точности то же самое, что было! То есть вычитание единицы не влияет на ситуацию, потому что единица влияет на те цифры, которые не хранятся, она как бы *слишком маленькая*. Подробнее об этом есть [здесь](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/unexpected-effects/). Там на примере игрушечного формата чисел с плавающей запятой идёт рассказ об этом и некоторых других неожиданных эффектах.

Далее вы спрашиваете какое максимальное число этим свойством не обладает. Коль скоро у типа float 23 бита отводится под цифры (мантисса), а ещё один бит всегда единица, мы получаем, что из чисел вплоть до `2**24` можно вычитать единицу и она БУДЕТ вычитаться корректно. Однако далее между `2**24` и `2**25` числа идут с шагом два, поэтому каждое второе при вычитании единицы будет посередине между чётным и нечётным числами, а потому по правилу округления [nearest-to-even, half-to-even](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/rounding-modes/) число будет округляться вниз (к чётному). Таким образом, на этом интервале все ЧЁТНЫЕ числа, НЕ делящиеся на `4`, будут уменьшаться на 2 при попытке отнять `1`. Остальные числа НЕ будут уменьшаться. Например, число `33554430` (не делится на `4`) станет равным `33554428`, однако при повторном вычитании `1` ничего не изменится. Кстати, число `33554430=2**25-2` и есть максимальное, о котором вы просите. Однако если вам нужно, чтобы и предыдущее (полученное после вычитания 1) тоже нормально вычиталось, то тогда наибольшим будет `2**24+2`. После вычитания 1 вы получите `2**24` (то есть оно уменьшится на 2) и далее при вычитании 1 будет уменьшаться на 1.

Для double это будет `2**53+2 = 9007199254740994` (если нужно, чтобы все предыдущие вычитались нормально) и `2**54-2 = 18014398509481982` (если после вычитание 1 оно уменьшится на 2 и повторное вычитание не даст результата).

Comment: Итак, безопасные диапазоны (чтобы в их пределах точно не было бага, и при отнятии, и при добавлении единицы): float – от -16_777_215 до 16_777_215; double – от -9_007_199_254_740_99**1** до 9_007_199_254_740_99**1**.  Так?

Comment: А поменяются ли эти диапазоны, если у чисел ещё и после точки будут значения?

Comment: Да, похоже что вы правы, если нужно именно И прибавлять, И отнимать. Если бы нужно было только что-то одно, то диапазон был бы чуть шире. Если после точки будут значения, то вопрос не совсем корректный. Дело в то, что у этих предельных значений после точки уже ничего быть не может, просто не хватит места. То есть числа  `16'777'215.5` уже не существует в природе чисел float. Однако если числа будут меньше, то там без разницы, что будет после запятой, потому что они всё равно останутся чувствительными к единице. Но строго математическое объяснение - это довольно долго для комментария.

Comment: То есть, например, число (float)`8388607.5` будет чувствительным к 1 в любую сторону, но если прибавить 1, то получится не `8388608.5` (такого числа нет), а `8388608`. Однако это всё-таки будет другое число, что вам и надо. Так что будьте осторожны, мне кажется, что вы когда задаёте вопросы даже не представляете, что помимо ответов на них нужно знать ещё много чего другого, чтобы не напороться на другие грабли, о которых не знали.

Comment: Существует ли готовое единое решение от: 1) неточности дробей после мат. операций (2.0 - 1.1 = не 0,9), 2) проблемы с этой страницы? (BigDecimal не решает второе, у BigInteger нету дробей). Мне кажется, можно было бы сделать класс, который бы хранил long (или хранил BigInteger - если надо вообще чуть-ли без ограничений по длине) число отдельное для целой части и отдельно для дробной.

Comment: Да, таким решением является класс рациональных чисел, числитель и знаменатель которых - BigInteger. Я не знаю есть ли такой класс в Java (я не пишу на нём), но его нетрудно написать самому. Дело в том, что любое  дробное число, которое хранится в памяти компьютера, оно всё равно будет конечным по длине, а значит оно будет рациональным и будет представимо в виде дроби. Но минуса тут два: вы теряете скорость и память. А ещё нужно постоянно конвертировать между числами с точкой и дробями.

Comment: Жесть, Excel-2016 аналогичным образом ограничен, даже для денежных форматов изменяет последнюю цифру 9_007_199_254_740_992 на 0, и отличий таких не видит.

Comment: Да, потому что там тот же самый формат IEEE-754, и он используется почти повсеместно. Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то прошу отметить ответ как правильный и завершить разговор не по теме. Для других вопросов давайте заводить новые темы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так проверить:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float i;
    for (i = 1; i < 1e38; i *= 10) {
        System.out.println(i + " "
            + (Float.MAX_VALUE-i == Float.MAX_VALUE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Заминусовали))) И тем не менее, если вы запустите этот код, то увидите, что true меняется на false между значениями i 1.0E31 и 1.0E32. А это в некоторой степени отвечает на вопрос 2 топикстартера. По крайней мере, показывает порядок искомых чисел.

Comment: Я бы в каждому числу от нуля прибавлял и отнимал единицу. Первое true (не обнаружил разницу) – верх диапазона, чувствительного на единицу, выходим из цикла. Тоже самое ниже нуля – низ диапазона.